# Multiple posts to DB with Linq

Tags: database, linq, pooling

if i have two thousand webusers each sumbmitting a post to sqldb through website at the same time same tables, will linq handle this without any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you create a fresh data context in each request, it'll handle it just as well as any other approach. If you genuinely have two thousand concurrent requests, I don't believe they'll all *actually* be served at the same time anyway - assuming you're using ASP.NET in a normal way, I suspect you'll run out of threads in the threadpool anyway.

What kind of problems were you anticipating? Obviously there'll be the normal DB concurrency problems to contend with - handling concurrent updates etc. LINQ to SQL makes it relatively easy to detect and handle these, but I strongly recommend that you get a suitable book to guide you through the process.